# How to reverse the direction of bouncing ball equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, physics

How to reverse the direction of bouncing ball equation?

The solution is detailed here:

http://reactorlab.net/resources-folder/matlab/pdf-link-folder/bouncing_ball_equations.pdf

In particular "Using the analytical solution for this case".

My problem. If I want to make the ball bounce off horizontal surfaces (e.g. top/bottom in box), then what do I need to adjust?

I've tried reversing the $+$ to $-$ by logic that the equation is basically:

start point + add something

so that the "add something" would define the curve, which goes "positive", because there's $+$. But this doesn't work. I cannot adjust gravity, because it doesn't make physical sense to adjust it. I cannot adjust $v_0$, because the reversing of direction is not related to an alteration in velocity (in this case).

---

Problem explanation:

Imagine that you want to make the particle bounce in a box in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For vertical directions one simply reverses the $x$: $x + \Delta x$ becomes $x - \Delta x$. But for horizontal?

---

Actually I noticed that it's described in the paper and it seems to work:

p. 2.

**QUESTION**

But why does one have to set $t=0$ at collision?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Does that make physical sense?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not sure if I understand your $t_{new}=t_{max}-t_{old}$? So say we hit the wall at $t=20$ and the ball bounces until $t=100$ in total. Then we take $t_{new}=100-20=80$? So we continue the animation at the hit point from $t=80$? How does this guarantee anything about the direction?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Imagine that you want to make the particle bounce in a box. For vertical directions one simply reverses the $x$: $x + \Delta x$ becomes $x - \Delta x$. But for horizontal?

Comment: You want to simulate/analyze *a bounce* as opposed to *revert the motion*. I misunderstood. Sorry.

Comment: The rest depends on the direction of the wall the ball is bouncing from. You have to tell us the meaning of the coordinates to get specific formulas. As in which coordinate changes when we go up/down, which corresponds to left/right etc.

Comment: And, is this 2D or 3D? Are the "walls" only horizontal/vertical or is an incline possible?

Comment: Your teacher wants you to write a program which simulates the movement, using that equation in the PDF? Looks doable, just be careful, that after the moment of collision you have to change most parameters: $y_0, v_0 , t$ (The "timer" resets to 0, the horizontal velocity (on a vertical wall) negates, the starting height gets the y coordinate at the collision.) So if the ball moves left and collides with the wall with ($v_x$, $v_y$) then after the collision the starting speed vector will be: (-$v_x$, $v_y$). The calculation is not continuous, you have to separate the phases between collisions.